# Id in Database what datatype use?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am working with Access database for a C# winform application.I want to create software, which stores the patient's details.I have assigned a patient_Id for each patient, Patient_Id is of "AutoNumber" datatype so that it will automatically increment. My problem is when same patient comes again then New Patient_Id automatically generated to store his new current data, but for same patient I want only one ID.

Comment: umm... if it's a repeat patient, why are you inserting a NEW record for that patient? shouldn't part of the signup process be to see if the patient record exists already, and just re-using that id? `if (patient_exists()) { get_existing_id(); } else { get_new_id(); }`

Comment: My client required the software should store all data whenever patient came(he need that details because it help him to see the progress of the Patient health) I appreciate your solution but  if I retrieve the existing Patient PatientId and store patient data then it will be added to the single row then if same patient comes once again it will be make an inflexibility(To analyze the data)to my client to retrieve previous 2 data and continue his work.

Comment: then your table design is totally wrong. you should have at least TWO tables: `patient` and `visits`. you only insert into `patient` when you create a new patient, and insert a new record into `visits` each time they walk in the door.

Comment: Yes I think this can be best solution for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Use some unique data as a field in your patient table (such as social security) and when a patient comes, look up this unique number and determine if he is a new patient or a returning one. This is a simple SELECT query something like:

```
"SELECT patient_Id FROM tPatients WHERE SSN=@sNum"
```